# ReactJS Conditional Rendering: Component being rendered even though rendering conditions are not met

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

**CONTEXT:**

I only have this problem when I route **directly** to a modal route (putting the link in the url bar and pressing enter).

`this.props.photoId` is actually a `this.props.routeParams.photoId` that is passed into this component from the parent.

---

When the parent component mounts, it renders out its contents as expected. When a photo on this parent component is clicked,the app routes from `myapp.com/parentContainer` to `myapp.com/parentContainer/:photoId`. When this `:photoId` `routeParam` is present in the route, it is used to conditionally render a modal component. When a "close" button on the modal is clicked, the app routes back to `myapp.com/parentContainer` losing the `:photoId` routeParam, and thus closing the modal.

I am really at a loss. I have been using these patterns to render react components throughout my project without problems however I have a problem in this seemingly non-unique scenario:

```
...

render(){

  return(
    typeof this.props.photoId != 'undefined'
  ?
    <PhotoModal/>
  :
    null
  )
}
```

What I am noticing, is that even though `this.props.photoId` is `undefined`, it still renders `<PhotoModal/>`?

**Again**, When I route into the parent component and open the modal from the parent component the modal will close as expected, this problem only happens when I route directly to the modal route -when this happens the parent component renders, the modal renders as expected, but when I close the modal and lose the routeParam the modal does not close. This only happens when I route directly to the modal route from an external link / using the url bar. When I start in the parent component the conditional routeParam modal opening/closing functionality works 100% as expected.

I am receiving no errors or warnings, and I am able to see that the `routeParam` is in fact undefined, yet the component is not updating itself. I have no `shouldComponentUpdate()` clauses, so nothing should be preventing it especially since it is aware of the prop change.

Comment: maybe undefined without quotes

Comment: Add a `console.log(typeof this.props.photoId)` to `render`. Maybe you're accidentally converting `photoId` to a string, and the prop value is the string `"undefined"` instead of `undefined`.

Comment: Nope that’s not it and even if I do some other convention routeParam sending methods like if(this.props.someRouteParam) it still doesn’t work. All this being said my conditional statements are working when I route in from the parent it is only when I directly route to the modal with the routeParam that it does not work

Comment: @connected_user when a variable is not defined, javascript assigns undefined to it. And undefined is itself a javascript global variable. You shouldn't quote undefined during comparison. You are comparing undefined as if it is a string. Remove the quotes in undefined and test your code.

Comment: @divine I will try that out, but if that is the case why are my conditional statements working perfectly if I just don't route in directly but from the parent component/route?

Comment: @connected_user are you trying to extract photoId  from the url myapp.com/parentContainer/:photoId ?

Comment: @divine Yes, it is a `routeParam`

Comment: @connected_user if it is a route param , then you should be using this.props.match.params.photoId  to extract data from the route as of react-router.4.2

Comment: @divine I am in react-router v3.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to have type check as well:

```
typeof this.props.photoId !== 'undefined'
```

Comment: typeof this.props.photoId returns string

Comment: Sorry for that typo. Thanks for correcting. :) @divine

Answer (score 0):

The best way to conditionally render a component in React: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Update your code to:

```
render() {
  return this.props.photoId ? <PhotoModal /> : null
}
```

This will also handle checking `null`, `false` and `0`.

Comment: I have tried this, and still no dice. The way I originally posted, this way, and all other commonly seen conditional statements all work when routing in from the parent component. They just don't work when I route directly to the route in question, with the route param ... well it does work, its just that when I 'close' the modal and route back to the base route, the modal component stays rendered even though props are changing.