# Conditional JSX renders despite condition not being met

Tags: reactjs, emotion

I have a component that conditionally renders. Despite the condition not being met, it seems to be attempting to render anyway (and I get an error).

A simplified example:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const [state, setState] = useState(null)
console.log(state)
console.log(typeof state)

return (
  <div>
    {state && 
      <div>
        {state.map(element => <div>{element.title}</div>)}
      </div>
    }
  </div>
)
```

I get the error: "Cannot read property 'map' of null". I'm quite sure that nothing after `state &&` should fire so I'm stumped as to what's going on.

I want to keep `null` as the initial value of my state if possible (this bug goes away if I provide an empty array).

I've tried variations of the condition, including:

- `state !== null`
- `typeOf state === 'object'`
- adding the same `state &&` condition before the `map`

**Edit:**

`console.log(state)` prints `null` but `console.log(typeof state)` prints `object`; at no point is `state` updated and `null` is printed at the same time as `object` so it's a bit confusing, though nonetheless this identifies the source of the problem.

It's been pointed out to me that `typeof null` is indeed `object`.

I'm using `@emotion/react` which handles the `jsx` so the issue may stem from there.

Comment: I think you have typo in there with the missing ```useState```. However, are you sure you are not setting a state somewhere in the component or have another variable with the same name that could cause it? What happens if you rename it from state to something else?

Comment: I just double-checked and haven't repeated it anywhere (It's only called state in my example). The bug goes away if i provide an initial value of an empty array.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The conditional should never be triggered. Here is a code sandbox example of this https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-ritchie-s7xrz
There must be more going on in your code to cause the behaviour you see.

Comment: Of course. I've written conditional JSX 100s of times and haven't encountered this before. My case doesn't seem to be unique: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49821621/reactjs-conditional-rendering-component-being-rendered-even-though-rendering-co.

Comment: That's interesting. What do you get when you console the state and the type of it?

Comment: I think you cracked it. console.log(state) prints 'null' but console.log(typeof state) prints 'object'!

Comment: It still shouldn't throw that error, right? since it is null and you are doing conditional render. What if you will simplify it to just this ```{state && state.map(element => <div>{element.title}</div>)}```

Comment: I don't think it should throw that error nor should typof return 'object'. That condition doesn't make a difference.

Comment: > console.log(state) prints 'null' but console.log(typeof state) prints 'object'! 
Because the type of `null` is `object`.

Comment: ```null``` is an ```object``` type, so that's correct https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null

Answer (score 0):

You are forget to initiate `useState`.

> And also don't forget to import the `useState` from react on top of the
> page

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'; //from react
const [state, setState] = useState(null) // missing useState
```

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, but I just forgot to include it in my example; useState with an initial value exists in my code.

Comment: That's a valid point but obviously not a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define your states in useState hook.

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react';

const [state, setState] = useState(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for this:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const [state, setState] = useState([])

return (
  <div>
    {state.length > 0 && 
      <div>
        {state.map(element => <div>{element.title}</div>)}
      </div>
    }
  </div>
)
```

Due to JSX declarative nature, the compiler engine has to run `state.map(...)` like everything you've put in the curly brackets to be able to render JSX, that's why runtime error happens, though element will not be rendered. In order to avoid this error, you can write it like this  `{state && state.map(element => <div>{element.title}</div>)}`

Comment: This does indeed work as I mentioned in the post. What do you mean by "execute all the code from right to left that's why runtime error happens"?

Comment: Compiler engine has to run `state.map(...)` to be able to render JSX. It's done recursively, that's what I mean.